# How many transactions per second can the Solana blockchain handle?

Tags: performance, transactions

Solana is usually described as the fastest blockchain in world, but it reality, how many transactions can it handle per second (e.g. in mainnet)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [whitepaper](https://solana.com/solana-whitepaper.pdf), theoretically 710,000 tps.
Today, Solana is still in mainnet-beta. Recently, Solana has been doing about ~3000 tps according to [solanabeach](https://solanabeach.io/).

Answer (score 7):

The actual (as opposed to theoretical) number has been changing over time.  Real-world use has shown some issues that are being addressed (defi bots slamming the network, for example) that have impacted network performance.  As more efficient code evolves and protection against flooding the network with transactions increases, I expect normal TPS to increase as well.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Solana overview here - https://www.alchemy.com/solana - Solana can process about 4k txns per second wiht txn costs less than $0.01. The estimate is based on gas fees, which ultimately determine the processing speed. This is also an interesting read if you wanna nerd out on some numbers